# Retrieving data from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I generate such array. How can I access the body of the return? I got a loop to get the data values to recieve this list build. I know how to get the totalResults but I can't get deeper in the array. Thanks.

```
foreach ($searchres as $videout){
echo '<li id="cNa9dzezrd8"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/cNa9dzezrd8/0.jpg"><br>';
echo '<div class="description">';
echo '<h3>Danny McCarthy - Silver Scrape...</h3>';
echo '<span>Author : </span> Kavvson<br>';
echo '<span>Views : </span> 161654<br>';
echo '</div></li>';
}
```

The array

```
array(4) {
  ["totalResults"]=>
  string(3) "588"
  ["startIndex"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["itemsPerPage"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["results"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(12) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(11) "cNa9dzezrd8"
      ["title"]=>
      string(67) "Danny McCarthy - Silver Scrapes ( Extended culineR & Kavvson Edit )"
      ["description"]=>
      string(160) "SoundCloud : Original version : Danny McCarthy - Silver Scrapes Edited by culineR and Me {} culineR www.Facebook.com/devonculineR www.Sou..."
      ["uploaded"]=>
      string(19) "04/05/2013 00:20:51"
      ["duration"]=>
      string(3) "274"
      ["author"]=>
      string(8) "kavvsona"
      ["category"]=>
      string(5) "Music"
      ["url"]=>
      string(71) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNa9dzezrd8&feature=youtube_gdata_player"
      ["rating"]=>
      string(8) "4.973549"
      ["views"]=>
      string(6) "161654"
      ["comments"]=>
      string(3) "147"
      ["thumbnails"]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(39) "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/cNa9dzezrd8/0.jpg"
        [1]=>
        string(39) "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/cNa9dzezrd8/1.jpg"
        [2]=>
        string(39) "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/cNa9dzezrd8/2.jpg"
        [3]=>
        string(39) "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/cNa9dzezrd8/3.jpg"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `$arr` holds your array, then try,

```
foreach($arr['results'] as $ar){
  echo $ar['id']; // and so on
}
```

Comment: Yep this helps quite.